# How to deal with a non-force-sensitive character trying to harvest a saber crystal?

Tags: lore, player-characters, star-wars-saga-edition

Three of my characters are close to lvl 7 and plan to enter the crystal cave on Mygeeto to harvest their own kyber crystal for their future weapons. This will be a standalone sidequest for them.

One of them is a scout with absolutely no force sensitivity. His goal is to build a weapon based on ligthsaber technology. He has no intention in becoming Force sensitive.

In my vision of the Star Wars universe one simply cannot power a weapon with a crystal without using the Force to build it, the item will explode. He has been warned in and out of character at several occasions.

But I'm really ensure how to deal with the cave part. It is supposed to give Force-induced vision to padawans to scare them or make them give up.

I don't remember any instance of non-force-sensitive in movies or the novels I read going into this kind of place.

I cannot forbid him to go as his character knows the location now. I do not want them to harvest many crystal to benefit from it (they are quite rare and worth a lot of money).

Should I let him take any crystal he find?
Should I not let him find any crystal?
Should I make the vision so strong his character will give up?

Comment: is this more of a rules question, or [tag:lore] question?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. There is no indication in the rulebook about what is or not possible. So maybe more lore indeed. I will add the tag.

Comment: Why is it "a standalone sidequest" for 3 out of 5 people if there are only 2 force sensitives?

Comment: Because the scout has been willing to build a weapon based on light-saber technology since the beginning of the campaign (a year ago). They met a Jedi Master who gave one of the Force sensitive character the location of a cristal cave, and the scout decided to tag along/was invited to come by the Force sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I think any scenario where you give everyone in the group a cool thing except you leave one player out for a weird reason is going to end up poorly.

Going by the new movies the deathstar was in part powered by lots and lots and lots of kyber crystals. (Rogue One). Wether you consider that part of Star Wars canon is up to you, but even in the expanded universe usually light sabers do not require jedi, it's just anyone who isn't a force sensitive is better served by a blaster since they cannot block blasters.

Just let your scout player have a souped up blaster or upgrade his ship weapons with the kyber. I doubt it'd be that difficult to make it balanced.

If you absolutely have to have the kyber crystals explode, have him gather up a bunch of them, send him on a sidequest, then have him learn how to construct kybernades that can't be force pushed, explodes and covers everything in the blast radius in kyberdust which disturbs force powers. Then he has a cool thing, useful for boss battles, but it's situational, consumable, and difficult to replenish. That way both your and his vision of the setting remain intact.

As for the cave, the easiest would have the force presence be potent enough he also gets the visions. Perhaps they are weaker or more distorted than the others though.

Comment: The character is not Force Sensitive. Nobody is being left "out for a weird reason". The player chose to make the character non-Force Sensitive, and has to accept the repercussions of that choice.

Comment: As a side note, there are 5 players in the group, only 2 are Force Sensitive.

Comment: As far as I remember SW lore, nothing alive is 100% disconnected from the force is that right?

Comment: I would think so. By the rules, every character can use Force Point, but for non-sensitive players it is percieved as "experience or intuition".

Comment: Based on this answer : https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/26843/does-construction-of-a-lightsaber-require-use-of-the-force user59614, it is required to use the Force to build a ligthsaber and power it correctly.
The kybernades could be a good idea though.

Answer (score -3):

> Should I let him take any crystal he find?

If you think that would be the most fun way for your game to go.

> Should I not let him find any crystal?

If you think that would be the most fun way for your game to go.

> Should I make the vision so strong his character will give up?

You can’t. You can make the vision as strong as you like but it’s his character so it’s his choice if he gives up.

It’s your choice if his choice results in his death.